# SQl server duplicate joins issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

can anyone please help: I tried to join with duplicate values but it is not coming as I wanted.

```
CREATE TABLE #TestTable1 ([No] varchar(50),[Value1] float,[Desc] varchar(50))
insert into #TestTable1 ([No],[Value1],[Desc])
Values 
 (N'123953',427.2,N'Basic Hours')
,(N'123953',106.8,N'Basic Hours')
,(N'123953',213.6,N'Basic Hours')
,(N'123953',213.6,N'Basic Hours')
,(N'123953',213.6,N'Basic Hours')
,(N'123953',213.6,N'Basic Hours')
,(N'123953',105.6,N'Basic Hours')


CREATE TABLE #TestTable2 ([No] varchar(50),[Value2] float,[Desc] varchar(50))
insert into #TestTable2 ([No],[Value2],[Desc])
Values 
 (N'123953',553.02,N'Basic Hours')
,(N'123953',446.67,N'Basic Hours')
,(N'123953',427.2,N'Basic Hours')
,(N'123953',106.8,N'Basic Hours')
,(N'123953',213.6,N'Basic Hours')
,(N'123953',213.6,N'Basic Hours')
,(N'123953',213.6,N'Basic Hours')
,(N'123953',105.6,N'Basic Hours')
```

Desired Output:

```
 [No],[Desc],[Value1],[Value2]

 (N'123953',N'Basic Hours',427.2,427.2)
,(N'123953',N'Basic Hours',106.8,106.8)
,(N'123953',N'Basic Hours',213.6,213.6)
,(N'123953',N'Basic Hours',213.6,213.6)
,(N'123953',N'Basic Hours',213.6,213.6)
,(N'123953',N'Basic Hours',213.6,NULL)
,(N'123953',N'Basic Hours',105.6,105.6)
```

Note: I can't join on Value field for other reasons.

I tried to use `row_number()` but still not coming as my desired output.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, what is the relationship between these 2 tables that share no distinct ID/foreign key?

Comment: @Larnu, unfortunately, I don't have any other Id/foreign key to make it unique

Comment: That wasn't what I was asking. I'm asking what the relationship between the 2 tables is, as there isn't an obvious one (considering you said that you can't use `value1 = value2` in the `JOIN`, then what determines the relationship?).

Comment: _I can't join on Value field for other reasons_ Alright, then join those tables on what? `T1.No = T2.No`? _I tried to use row_number() but still not coming as my desired output_ Can you please post the query you try it and brings unexpected result?

Comment: I need to compare two data sets and bring first dataset results if matches bring both values if not NULL.

Comment: Curious to know why you cannot use value as a join condition

Comment: Also, it looks like if the value appears in both tables (i.e. 213.6)  you are showing null because it repeats 4 times in table 1 but only 3 times in table 2?

Comment: @Dohsan, in some cases Value2 may not match with Value1 but still, I need to return both values ex: 427.2,200.2

Comment: How are you determining the "first" value? There's no columns you can order by in your data to return your data is the same order it is inserted.

Comment: @Dohsan, the value in table1 got 4 times but table2 got only 3 times, so I have to return NULL for that

Comment: What should happen if the situation is reversed, .. if Table1 has 4 items and Table2 has 3 items?  Would your result have Value1 is NULL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does this look?

```
WITH Table1
AS
(
    SELECT  T1.No,
            T1.[Desc],
            T1.Value1,
            CAST(T1.Value1 AS VARCHAR) + '~' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T1.No, T1.Value1 ORDER BY T1.Value1 ASC) AS VARCHAR(2)) AS RN
    FROM    @TestTable1 AS T1
),
Table2
AS
(
    SELECT  T2.No,
            T2.[Desc],
            T2.Value2,
            CAST(T2.Value2 AS VARCHAR) + '~' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T2.No, T2.Value2 ORDER BY T2.Value2 ASC) AS VARCHAR(2)) AS RN
    FROM    @TestTable2 AS T2
)
SELECT  T.No,
        T.[Desc],
        T.Value1,
        T2.Value2
FROM    Table1 AS T
LEFT
JOIN    Table2 AS T2
        ON  T.No = T2.No
            AND T.RN = T2.RN;
```

Comment: That's what I am looking for. Thanks a lot

Comment: I'd be a little careful here. You could get false positives. For example, if you had a row with the value `100` and then 3 rows with the value `99` then you would get a `JOIN` between the 2nd row of `99` and the first of `100`. (`100  + '1' = 101 = 99 + '2'`)

Comment: Good point, perhaps with some kind of separator symbol inbetween. Although still not sure why value can't be used in the join :)

Comment: I'd added the missing cast to the value as well so it shouldn't

Comment: Hi @Dohsan, I got another situation with the above example, can you help?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to get your desired output:

```
;WITH CTE1 AS
(
    SELECT  [No],
            [Value1],
            [Desc], 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [No], [Value1] ORDER BY @@SPID) As rn
    FROM #TestTable1
),  CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT  [No],
            [Value2],
            [Desc], 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [No], [Value2] ORDER BY @@SPID) As rn
    FROM #TestTable2
)

SELECT  C1.[No],
        C1.[Desc],
        C1.[Value1],
        C2.[Value2]
FROM CTE1 AS C1
LEFT JOIN CTE2 AS C2
    ON C1.[No] = C2.[No]
    AND C1.rn = C2.rn
    AND C1.[Value1] = C2.[Value2]
```

Comment: Glad to help :-). BTW, the false positives Larnu wrote about in the comments of the other answers will not happen with this one.

Comment: Hi @Zohar Peled, I got another situation with the above example, can you help?

Comment: perhaps. Post another question, me or someone else will probably be able to answer it.

Comment: Hi @Zohar Peled,Sure, Thanks

Comment: posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53416582/sql-server-duplicate-joins-issue-with-different-elements. Thanks