# SQl server duplicate joins issue with different elements

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Sorry, I am posting again with one more requirement.

can anyone please help: I tried to join with duplicate values but it is not coming as I wanted.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TestTable1
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TestTable2

CREATE TABLE #TestTable1 ([No] varchar(50),[Value1] float,[Desc] varchar(50))
insert into #TestTable1 ([No],[Value1],[Desc])
Values 
 (N'123953',300.02,N'Extra Pay')
,(N'123953',427.2,N'Basic Hours')
,(N'123953',106.8,N'Basic Hours')
,(N'123953',213.6,N'Basic Hours')
,(N'123953',213.6,N'Basic Hours')
,(N'123953',213.6,N'Basic Hours')
,(N'123953',213.6,N'Basic Hours')
,(N'123953',105.6,N'Basic Hours')


CREATE TABLE #TestTable2 ([No] varchar(50),[Value2] float,[Desc] varchar(50))
insert into #TestTable2 ([No],[Value2],[Desc])
Values 
 (N'123953',200.02,N'Extra Pay')
,(N'123953',553.02,N'Basic Hours')
,(N'123953',446.67,N'Basic Hours')
,(N'123953',427.2,N'Basic Hours')
,(N'123953',106.8,N'Basic Hours')
,(N'123953',213.6,N'Basic Hours')
,(N'123953',213.6,N'Basic Hours')
,(N'123953',213.6,N'Basic Hours')
,(N'123953',105.6,N'Basic Hours')
```

Desired Output:

```
[No],[Desc],[Value1],[Value2],[MatchResult]


,(N'123953',N'Extra Pay',300.02,200.02, False)
,(N'123953',N'Basic Hours',427.2,427.2, True)
,(N'123953',N'Basic Hours',106.8,106.8, True)
,(N'123953',N'Basic Hours',213.6,213.6, True)
,(N'123953',N'Basic Hours',213.6,213.6, True)
,(N'123953',N'Basic Hours',213.6,213.6, True)
,(N'123953',N'Basic Hours',213.6,NULL,NULL)
,(N'123953',N'Basic Hours',105.6,105.6, True)
```

Comment: What did you try and what was wrong with the result?

Comment: [Previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53411502/sql-server-duplicate-joins-issue). What's wrong with the accepted answer in the previous question? Why haven't you included the code you are using? What have you tried/changed to get your *new* expected results? Stack overflow isn't a free coding and support service, please don't treat it like one. If you don't know what/how the code works then you shouldn't be using the code you've been supplied; it's your responsibility to support it not the volunteers here.

Comment: @Larnu, I know but I got different requirement now. sorry about that

Comment: The requirement changing is fine, but please do show your attempt to meet the new requirement; using the code you were previously supplied or your own full attempt.

Comment: is your match on 300.02,200.02 a typo?  Otherwise I'm not clear what constitutes a match/non match.  Why would the 'spare' 213.6 then join to nothing for example?

Comment: what is your true/false column?  Maybe it's a partial match, however there are other 'partial matches' possible - how do you choose what they should be?

Comment: @Cato, it's not typo. if row existed and value mismatch then it should show both vales and say False to [MatchResult] field.

Comment: so why is 300.02 matched with 200.02 in particular, but not matched with 446.67 - what is the criterion in use?

Comment: @Cato, 446.67 is not in the first table so we can ignore them (446.67 & 553.02)

Comment: 200.02 isn't in the first table either, but you haven't ignored it.  Can you explain what you're aiming at here? - otherwise it just looks like you've got an unexplained link between two values

Comment: are you using the 'physical' order in which you inserted the records?  A problem there is that rows in SQL tables have no physical order, you would need to create an additional sequence field, or specify a sort order.  I don't think you've given any sort order there, the rows seem unsorted.

Comment: What's the rule here? Basic hours should show null in value2 and MatchResult if there is no match, but Extra Pay should show both values and false? what if there's an Extra Pay record only in one table?

Answer (score 0):

--it looks to me like you should be able to force row_numbers onto duplicate rows, and therfore achieve a one-to-one join, leaving no match on the right as null

```
SELECT Q1.No, Q1.[desc], Q1.[value1],q2.[value2] FROM 

 (SELECT [NO] , 
            value1, 
            [desc], 
            ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by [NO] , value1, [desc] order by [no]) RN 
                FROM #TestTable1
  ) Q1

 LEFT JOIN

 (SELECT [NO] , 
            value2, 
            [desc], 
            ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by [NO] , value2, [desc] order by [no]) RN 
                FROM #TestTable2
  ) Q2

 ON Q1.Value1=Q2.Value2 AND 
        Q1.[No] = Q2.[NO] AND 
            Q1.[desc] = Q2.[Desc] AND 
                Q1.RN = Q2.rn
```